# How to configure CocoaPods in Travis CI? (multi-language project)

Tags: cocoapods, travis-ci

I'm trying to get Travis CI set up on a multi-language project. (This [PR](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-vision/pull/24).) The problem I'm having is the `pod install` step keeps segfaulting.

`/Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13 revision 50299) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]`

If I use Ruby 1.9.3 (by using `language: ruby` and setting `rvm: 1.9.3` in `.travis.yml`) as suggested in the [common Travis build problems](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#CocoaPods-fails-with-a-segmentation-fault) guide, then I get an error when I try to install CocoaPods.

`++gem install cocoapods -v 0.32.1
...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
    /Users/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby -rubygems /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake RUBYARCHDIR=/Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/1.9.1/xcodeproj-0.16.1 RUBYLIBDIR=/Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/1.9.1/xcodeproj-0.16.1
/Users/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for -std=c99 option to compiler... yes
checking for CoreFoundation... no
checking for main() in -lCoreFoundation... no
CoreFoundation is needed to build the Xcodeproj C extension.
*** extconf.rb failed ***`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the version of Ruby to 2.2.3 by setting `rvm: 2.2.3` fixed the issue for me.